# What is the closure of x = y in the river metric?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let the metric space be $\mathbb{R}^2 $ with the river metric, where the river is located on the x-axis.

The subset considered is $A = \left \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x=y \right \}$. What is the closure of the set?

I understand that the closure of the set is the intersection of all the closed sets that contain A, however, I have problems with imagining what it looks like in this metric.

EDIT: The jungle river metric is a metric where you move as if were supposed to follow the river when walking from one point to another, unless they are located in the same line perpendicular to the river. [Here's a quick visual guide.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s16B.png)

Comment: I think you should specify what the river metric is, because I don't think it is very widely used.

Comment: I think the river metric has $d(\langle x_1, y_1\rangle, \langle x_2, y_2\rangle) = |y_1| + |x_2-x_1| + |y_2|$.  (Go from the first point perpendicularly to the river, go along the river, then go to perpendicularly to the second point.)

Comment: @Mjd : and $d((x,y_1),(x,y_2)) = |y_2-y_1|$, hence it is a world with a river and many uncrossable valleys perpendicular to it, and the limiting case : the number of valleys $\to \infty$, when $x_1 \ne x_2$ two points don't lie in the same valley

Comment: for that metric the curve $x= y$ is a set of isolated points ? not so different to the set of rationals in $[0,1]$ with some weird metric making two rationals always "very far", and its closure is itself ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to approach the question is to determine what $\epsilon$-balls around different points look like when $\epsilon$ is small.

Consider a point $p=\langle x,y\rangle$ with $y\ne 0$: if $\epsilon\le|y|$, the open $\epsilon$-ball centred at $p$ is $$\{x\}\times(y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon)\;.$$ It’s not too hard to show that if $p\notin A$, then $p\notin\operatorname{cl}A$.

That leaves points on the $x$-axis. Can you work out what the $\epsilon$-ball centred at one of these points looks like? In case you get completely stuck, I’ve left a qualitative description in the spoiler-protected block below.

> It’s square rotated so that two of its corners are on the $x$-axis, and the other two are directly above and directly below the centre.

If the point on the $x$-axis is not the origin, can you find an $\epsilon$-ball around it that is disjoint from $A$?

Comment: The epsilon approach really made me understand this problem, thank you!

Comment: @Angelika: You’re welcome!